# I get an error i18n-0.6.4 when I run rake assets:precompile in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rake, assets

When I run `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`

I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@eapi4/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize': Could not find i18n-0.6.4 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

However all the gems are installed:

```
Using rake (10.1.0) 
Using i18n (0.6.4) 
Using minitest (4.7.5) 
Using multi_json (1.7.8) 
Using atomic (1.1.12) 
Using thread_safe (0.1.2) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.37) 
Using activesupport (4.0.0) 
Using builder (3.1.4) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using rack (1.5.2) 
Using rack-test (0.6.2) 
Using actionpack (4.0.0) 
Using mime-types (1.23) 
Using polyglot (0.3.3) 
Using treetop (1.4.14) 
Using mail (2.5.4) 
Using actionmailer (4.0.0) 
Using activemodel (4.0.0) 
Using activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3) 
Using arel (4.0.0) 
Using activerecord (4.0.0) 
Using addressable (2.3.2) 
Using annotate (2.5.0) 
Using bcrypt-ruby (3.1.1) 
Using sass (3.2.10) 
Using bootstrap-sass (2.3.2.1) 
Using highline (1.6.19) 
Using net-ssh (2.7.0) 
Using net-scp (1.1.2) 
Using net-sftp (2.1.2) 
Using net-ssh-gateway (1.2.0) 
Using capistrano (2.15.5) 
Using capistrano-ext (1.2.1) 
Using mini_portile (0.5.1) 
Using nokogiri (1.6.0) 
Using ffi (1.1.5) 
Using childprocess (0.3.5) 
Using libwebsocket (0.1.5) 
Using rubyzip (0.9.9) 
Using selenium-webdriver (2.25.0) 
Using xpath (0.1.4) 
Using capybara (1.1.2) 
Using orm_adapter (0.4.0) 
Using ckeditor (4.0.6) 
Using client_side_validations (3.2.2) from git://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations.git (at 4-0-beta) 
Using simple_form (3.0.0.rc) 
Using client_side_validations-simple_form (2.1.0) from git://github.com/saveritemedical/client_side_validations-simple_form.git (at master) 
Using coffee-script-source (1.6.3) 
Using execjs (1.4.0) 
Using coffee-script (2.2.0) 
Using thor (0.18.1) 
Using railties (4.0.0) 
Using coffee-rails (4.0.0) 
Using commonjs (0.2.6) 
Using delayed_job (4.0.0) 
Using delayed_job_active_record (4.0.0) 
Using warden (1.2.3) 
Using devise (3.0.2) 
Using diff-lcs (1.1.3) 
Using launchy (2.3.0) 
Using email_spec (1.5.0) 
Using factory_girl (4.2.0) 
Using factory_girl_rails (4.2.1) 
Using faker (1.2.0) 
Using font-awesome-rails (3.2.1.2) 
Using tilt (1.4.1) 
Using haml (4.0.3) 
Using haml-rails (0.4) 
Using hike (1.2.3) 
Using jbuilder (1.5.0) 
Using jquery-rails (3.0.4) 
Using jquery-ui-rails (4.0.4) 
Using json (1.8.0) 
Using kaminari (0.14.1) 
Using kgio (2.8.1) 
Using less (2.3.2) 
Using less-rails (2.3.3) 
Using libv8 (3.11.8.17) 
Using metaclass (0.0.1) 
Using mocha (0.14.0) 
Using negative_captcha (0.3.3) 
Using nested_form (0.3.2) 
Using nifty-generators (0.4.6) 
Using pg (0.16.0) 
Using rack-pjax (0.7.0) 
Using bundler (1.3.5) 
Using sprockets (2.10.0) 
Using sprockets-rails (2.0.0) 
Using rails (4.0.0) 
Using remotipart (1.2.1) 
Using safe_yaml (0.9.4) 
Using sass-rails (4.0.0) 
Using rails_admin (0.5.0) from git://github.com/sferik/rails_admin.git (at master) 
Using raindrops (0.12.0) 
Using rdoc (3.12.2) 
Using ref (1.0.5) 
Using rest-client (1.6.7) 
Using rspec-core (2.12.2) 
Using rspec-expectations (2.12.1) 
Using rspec-mocks (2.12.2) 
Using rspec-rails (2.12.2) 
Using rvm-capistrano (1.5.0) 
Using sdoc (0.3.20) 
Using sequel (3.20.0) 
Using shoulda-context (1.1.5) 
Using shoulda-matchers (2.3.0) 
Using shoulda (3.5.0) 
Using sinatra (1.0) 
Using spring (1.3.4) 
Using sqlite3 (1.3.8) 
Using taps (0.3.24) 
Using therubyracer (0.11.4) 
Using turbolinks (1.3.0) 
Using twitter-bootstrap-rails (2.2.7) 
Using uglifier (2.1.2) 
Using unicorn (4.6.3)
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: did you try to  run it with `bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`?

Comment: That worked thanks Andrey. How about making it an answer so I can give you the points

Comment: sure, glad it helped, added the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has something to do with gemsets.
Prepending `bundle exec` to the command makes it run in the context of your bundle, using the gems specified in your Gemfile (application's gems versions could differ from these, installed on your system).

So the solution is to run it as follows:

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```